# What are some good Electrical and Electronics blogs worth following?

Tags: reference

This is a soft question. I am newly admitted to Electronic and Electrical engineering . Under this branch there are multiple domains from which I may work in one of them in the future.

For knowing where is my particular interest in one of such particular domain, first of all I should know what are they (each domain) what are do's and don't. What is its scope and new technologies? And from the related blogs, sites I think that I could get such information.

So I want to ask about some good sites, magazines or blogs where I can get more info on the various fields and the latest trends about Electrical and Electronics research.

Or, should I just check out "classical" providers like Springer , IEEE Transactions , Elsevier etc ?

Comment: www.eevblog.com for nice bits and bobs of what Dave happens to think about, or EEVBlog and EEVBlog2 on Youtube for a ton of videos. Otherwise picking subjects to read about and just find articles from reasonable experts is the best way to get subject matter. For news and developments any magazine with some expert basis in the fields of your interest will do. Generic magazines will always have a generic editorial staff and offer the generic basics and regularly grossly simplified near to being misinterpreted, but may offer a jump off point for on-line research.

Comment: unless concentrating on one domain, keeping up to date with everything is  impossible

Comment: Your question can be modified. You have a point

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That probably depends on your interests. Some suggestions (in no specific order):

- http://www.ganssle.com/
- http://thesignalpath.com/blogs/
- http://www.crosstalkonline.org/
- http://circuitcellar.com/
- http://www.eetimes.com/
- http://www.edn.com/
- http://www.embedded.com/
- http://www.eevblog.com/
- http://www.bethesignal.com/bogatin/index.php
- https://www.reddit.com/r/ECE/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/electronics/

AND of course:

- https://electronics.stackexchange.com ;-)

Comment: I'll add an interesting link I discovered recently: http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/

Answer (score 3):

A few more :

- [Michael Barr](http://embeddedgurus.com/barr-code/) on embedded software, if you like C or have to use it anyway
- [Simon Wright](http://forward-in-code.blogspot.co.uk/) and [Maciej Sobczak](http://www.inspirel.com/articles.html) if you can choose Ada instead
- [Hackaday](http://hackaday.com/) for a mixed bunch including some outrageous projects
- [Jeri Ellsworth](https://www.youtube.com/user/jeriellsworth) for good intros on a bunch of circuits

Answer (score 3):

You're newly admitted. Stop what you're doing. Get a head start on the basics, and watch a couple of EEVBlog videos in your spare time. After a couple of years of coursework, your desired subfield will become obvious on its own. There's no need to force it.