# How can I get started with electronic engineering

Tags: programming

How can I get started with electronic engineering i have no experience what so ever but i do know programming languages like java and c sharp. so how can I get started i have budget like $100

Comment: Unfortunately this site is for Q and A that would stand the test of time and not solicit opinion.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate but seems to overlap with http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/179871/what-are-some-good-electrical-and-electronics-engineering-blogs-worth-following

Answer (score 2):

There are many online sources available. I suggest you look at the MOOC platforms [edx.org](http://www.edx.org) and [coursera.org](http://www.coursera.org). Below is list of suggested coursers ordered from beginner to advance.

- [Electronic Interfaces: Bridging the Physical and Digital Worlds from University of California at Berkeley](https://www.edx.org/course/electronic-interfaces-bridging-physical-uc-berkeleyx-ee40lx-0)
- [Circuits and Electronics from Massachusetts Institute of Technology](https://www.edx.org/course/circuits-electronics-mitx-6-002x-0)
- [Creative, Serious and Playful Science of Android Apps](https://www.coursera.org/course/androidapps101)
- [Embedded Systems - Shape The World from University of Texas at Austin](https://www.edx.org/course/embedded-systems-shape-world-utaustinx-ut-6-02x)
- [Cyber-Physical Systems from University of California at Berkeley](https://www.edx.org/course/cyber-physical-systems-uc-berkeleyx-eecs149-1x)
- [The Hardware/Software Interface from University of Washington](https://www.coursera.org/course/hwswinterface)

The above list is a short list of suggested free online coursers. The cost for following one or two of these courses can be managed under US $100. Also you can post any engineering questions here on [electronic stackexchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/180514/edit) or [engineering stackexchange](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/). This should get you started.

Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

Are you in college still or do you have any nights free? Take a college course, community college night class, a mook, or go to a robotics/chip maker/EE meetup. One of things you might find interesting is Instrucables. Sometimes the best way to learn is by doing. Make something simple you want and will actually finish. Another way is go to the thrift store and buy some broken electronics and learn how to troubleshoot then fix them.

http://www.instructables.com/tag/type-id/category-technology/

[How can I learn electronics at home?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28315/how-can-i-learn-electronics-at-home)

Comment: Im in second grade in highschool

Comment: Since you are highschool, I am assuming you live in USA based on the question, I suggest you take a close look at [Electronic Interfaces: Bridging the Physical and Digital Worlds](https://www.edx.org/course/electronic-interfaces-bridging-physical-uc-berkeleyx-ee40lx-0) This course just started. This could be a great summer learning experience.

Comment: And I recommend staying far, far away from instructables. Their circuits are usually scary and unsafe, and rarely do they follow proper engineering. It's good to tinker, but avoid sites that will give bad habits.

Comment: FWIW, most of the instructable circuits I've seen (aka. the ones that have shown up here) are awful.

Comment: I dont Live in USA i Live in turkey

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you will need to clarify what exactly do you mean by "How can I get started with electronic engineering" . Do you want to learn theory and stuff, or do you want a practical exposure and tinker around stuff ?

If you wish to learn theory and study electronics, grab some books on basics and / or find some courses. I would suggest you to start with electrical networks and electronic devices. These are the basic things you must know (apart from mathematics) before going any further. Further from there you can look into digital and analog electronics.

If however your intent is tinkering, I would suggest you to get some development board like Arduino or Raspberry Pi, a breadboard, few Leds, motors etc. There are plenty of good tutorials on the net like instructables which house a wide range of projects to cater to everyone's interests.