# How do I power a Twin Industries TW-E41-102B?

Tags: breadboard, logic-gates

I just bought a Twin Industries TW-E41-102B, and I'm new to physical logic gate stuff, how do I power the breadboard? Please help!

Comment: I have posted a like good beginner MOOC course [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/180512/how-can-i-get-started-with-electronic-engineering/180514#180514) that might be a great asset. You might want to consider following [Electronic Interfaces: Bridging the Physical and Digital Worlds from University of California at Berkeley](https://www.edx.org/course/electronic-interfaces-bridging-physical-uc-berkeleyx-ee40lx-0). This course is free and will help you get started. Let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: Ok then, very irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way, using a wall-wart or similar wall plug power supply or battery pack, courtesy of a [Sparkfun](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-breadboard/building-your-first-breadboard-circuit) tutorial:

[image]

If you get more involved you may wish to use a bench power supply that has banana jacks on it, in which case they will plug into the top of the colored binding posts, and only single wires will come from the binding posts to the breadboard. In the photo above, they're being used simply as tie points (so if you yank the cord it won't pull the wires out of the breadboard). Make sure nothing can short the binding posts on the bottom (they should be clear of the work surface by virtue of the rubber feet, but make sure nothing conductive gets under there).

Answer (score 0):

The breadboard itself doesn't need powering, since it is nothing more than a collection of passive conductors. It is quite common though to connect the two sets of parallel "power rails" above and below the main area of the breadboard (red to red and blue to blue) and supplying power via them, optionally connecting them to the binding posts if power will be supplied from a banana plug.

Comment: so it provides it's own "power"?

Comment: Well, no, you provide power from an external source to the circuitry formed on the breadboard. But the breadboard itself neither needs nor uses power.

Comment: That was not the question.